# App Engine - PHP Symfony - how to require login using app.yaml

Tags: php, symfony, google-app-engine

I am running a Symfony PHP project on App Engine flex environment.

My app.yaml looks like this:

```
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: public
  front_controller_file: index.php

env_variables:
    APP_ENV: "prod"

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

I need to make the entire app require login from a GSuite account. In other projects that use handlers, under the handlers I would place the line:

```
login: required
```

But with the app.yaml for this project I'm unsure where to place that line, to ensure entire app needs user to login. Where is it correct to place it?

Answer (score 5):

The `app.yaml` `login: required` (and `login: admin`) functionality is based on the `Users` service, which is specific for the standard environment application and is not supported in the flexible environment.

You need to handle that authentication logic inside your application code. The [Users](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/migrating#users) section of the [Migrating Services from the Standard Environment to the Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/migrating) guide mentions your available options:

> The Users service is not available outside of the standard
>   environment. You can use any HTTP-based authentication mechanism in
>   the flexible environment, such as:
>
> - [Google Identity Platform](https://developers.google.com/identity/), which provides many options for authentication and authorization of Google user accounts.
> - [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/), which provides authentication using username/password and federated identity using Google, Facebook,
>     Twitter, and more.
> - [Auth0](https://auth0.com/), which provides authentication with various identity providers and single sign-on features.
> - [OAuth 2.0](https://oauth.net/2/) and [OpenID Connect](http://openid.net/connect/) which provide federated identity from the provider of your choice. Google is an [OpenID
>     Connect identity provider](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect). There are also several [other](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID_Connect#Adoption)
>     providers available.
>
> Note that because the Users service is not available, it is not
>   possible to use [`app.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/appref) to make URLs accessible only by
>   administrators. You will need to handle this logic within your
>   application.

Comment: OK Interesting ... so I create client ID in console, and add the script and meta tag from Google to the head of my base template?

Comment: Sorry, I can't really help with how exactly it is done, I'm still using the standard environment :)